# executable created by pyinstaller doesn't run

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, crash, pyinstaller, executable

I'm creating a sudoku Solver on pygame, and now want to make an executable for the project, since you can't expect a user to know about programming, virtual environments, etc

I installed PyInstaller on my virtual environment, in pygame, and used the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

It worked.

However, I can't run the executable, inside the dist folder :(

When I try to click on the executable, on the paste, nothing happens. Using the terminal, I get the following error:

```
./main
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/lucas1809/Área de Trabalho/Projetos/sudokey/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "PyInstaller/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyInstaller' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[3920] Failed to execute script main
```

I don't think the main.py code is necessary, since It's running fine when executed in pycharm. But, if I'm wrong, I'll post the code

I'll be grateful If someone can help me with this problem. If you have some problem understanding, or I wasn't clear. Please, ask.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: Here is the "main.py" code:

```
import pygame, os, PyInstaller
from pygame.locals import *
from board import Board
from button import Button 

# Initialization and screen surface loading
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode()
screenSize = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
width = screenSize[0]
height = screenSize[1]
pygame.display.set_caption("Sudokey: Sudoku's Solver")

# Image and music loading
bgMenu = pygame.image.load("background/sudokey2Menu.png")
bgMenu = pygame.transform.scale(bgMenu, (width, height - 30))
bgStart = pygame.image.load("background/sudokeyCustom.png")
bgStart = pygame.transform.scale(bgStart, (width - 40, height - 55))
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/lullabyGhostInYourPiano.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
click = pygame.mixer.Sound("sons/click.ogg")

# Default screen and game state
running = 1
menu = 1
start = 0
credit = 0

# Mouse logic to detect click
currentSquare = (9, 9)
clickedCell = None

# Creating board using class "Board"
tabuleiro = Board()

# Creating menu buttons using class "Button"
buttonStart = Button(400, 186, 530, 90)
buttonTutorial = Button(400, 325, 530, 90)
buttonOptions = Button(400, 464, 530, 90)
buttonCredits = Button(400, 603, 530, 90)

# Creating start buttons using class "Button"
buttonSolve = Button(898, 40, 380, 80)
buttonReset = Button(898, 159, 380, 80)
buttonGoBack = Button(898, 279, 380, 80)
buttonOptionsStart = Button(898, 398, 380, 80)

# Font loading
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)


# Visually updates the board
def drawGrid(board):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if (board[i][j]):
                text = font.render(str(board[i][j]), True, (0, 0, 0))
                textRect = text.get_rect()
                textRect.center = (j * 90 + 45, i * 80 + 45)
                screen.blit(text, textRect)

# Plays music based on input
def jukebox(number):
    if number == 0:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    elif number == 1:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/lullabyGhostInYourPiano.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 2:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/adventureGhostInYourPiano.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 3:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/liebestrau.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 4:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/Kiss_the_Sky.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 5:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/Lullaby.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 6:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/Gentle_Breeze.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 7:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/Eternal_Hope.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 8:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/Pressure.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    elif number == 9:
        pygame.mixer.music.load("musica/01 To the Moon - Main Theme.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)


while running:
    while menu:
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(bgMenu, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                running = 0
                menu = 0
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                start = 1
                menu = 0
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                if buttonStart.isOn(x, y):
                    #click.play()
                    #click.stop()

                    print(x, y)
                    menu = 0
                    start = 1

                elif buttonTutorial.isOn(x, y):
                    print(x, y)
                    print('tutorial')
                    menu = 0
                    start = 1

                elif buttonOptions.isOn(x, y):
                    print(x, y)
                    print('Options')
                    menu = 0
                    start = 1

                elif buttonCredits.isOn(x, y):
                    print(x, y)
                    print('Credits')
                    menu = 0
                    start = 1

            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if (pygame.K_0 <= event.key <= pygame.K_9):
                    number = int(event.unicode)
                    jukebox(number)

    while start:
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(bgStart, (0, 0))
        drawGrid(tabuleiro.tabuleiro)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print('stopping')
                running = 0
                start = 0

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and (event.key == pygame.K_m or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                start = 0
                menu = 1

            if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP):
                coords = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                col = coords[1] // 80
                line = coords[0] // 90
                clickedCell = (line, col)

            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if (clickedCell != None):
                    if (pygame.K_0 <= event.key <= pygame.K_9):
                        line = clickedCell[1]
                        col = clickedCell[0]
                        number = int(event.unicode)
                        if 0 <= line <= 8 and 0 <= col <= 8:
                            tabuleiro.setCell(line, col, number)
                            clickedCell = None

            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    tabuleiro.findFirst()
                    tabuleiro.solve()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    tabuleiro.reset()


            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(x, y)

                if buttonSolve.isOn(x, y):
                    print('solving')
                    tabuleiro.solve()

                elif buttonReset.isOn(x, y):
                    tabuleiro.reset()
                    tabuleiro.show()

                elif buttonGoBack.isOn(x, y):
                    start = 0
                    menu = 1

                elif buttonOptionsStart.isOn(x, y):
                    start = 0
                    menu = 1

pygame.quit()
```

Obs: Button and Board are both classes I use to solve the game

Edit 2: The previous error was fixed! :)
Now, I just got another one, but this time, I can execute the file, but It closes right after

This is the mistake, now:

```
./main
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
  File "pygame/pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
  File "setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1457, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
[3816] Failed to execute script main
```

Looks like It has something to do with fonts, in pygame, but I don't see why. The code runs perfectly inside pycharm.

Maybe my pyinstaller is using a wrong version of pygame, and don't recognize the method? Doesn't make sense to me, but I don't know what can be causing this

Thanks in advance (again). I couldn't find help anywhere besides here

Comment: You should provide the minimum code that produce that problem. It looks like the exe is trying to setup PyInstaller....

Comment: all right. I'll do it right now. Did it! Also, thanks a lot for the fast answer. Hopefully you can help me now :)

Comment: oh, hold up. I should not import "PyInstaller", in the first line? I don't understand what you mean by "exe is trying to setup pyinstaller". Is that it?

Comment: Yes pyinstaller is a tool and should not be imported. The command you are using should work perfectly if you remove the import

Comment: hey. I am sorry for the late reply. You did It, that error is now fixed. Thank you so much :). Now I have another error, but I'll update the post again

Comment: thinking again, It would probably be better to ask another question, since the error of this question was solved. Will do that, but please, feel free to answer here. I would apreciate it

Comment: do you have embedded freesansbold.ttf in your exe or have it in the current directory ?

Comment: I don't have it. Pygame handles the situation in pycharm, I guess, so I never really had to download it. Thanks a lot, I think I got it. I should somehow download the font and put in the same directory as the project, right?

Comment: DUDE. It worked it! Seriously, thank you so much!!  :D

Comment: Your welcome. Please upvote comments that where usefull

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Here it goes!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put full file names like  this

```
pygame.font.Font('./freesansbold.ttf')
```